# How to install to latest node version on command prompt or powershell

Tags: node.js, git, powershell, lint, stylelint

I am trying to edit a BigCommerce theme using stencilLint. When I type the command:

```
PS C:\Users\joaom\OneDrive\Desktop\shelfology\cornerstone> stencil init
```

I get:

```
PS C:\Users\joaom\OneDrive\Desktop\shelfology\cornerstone> stencil init
C:\Users\joaom\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\cliCommon.js:47
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: You are running an unsupported version of node. Please upgrade to ^10.17 || ^12
    at checkNodeVersion (C:\Users\joaom\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\cliCommon.js:47:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joaom\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\bin\stencil-init.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
PS C:\Users\joaom\OneDrive\Desktop\shelfology\cornerstone>
```

Which is leaving me very confused. I downloaded the latest version of Node from nodejs.org directly, and it still prompts me to get the latest version. Do I have to do this through the command prompt? what would be the command? or what else am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also install it or only download it?

Comment: I installed it. When I type "node -v" I get "14.15.3", which is the latest version, which is why I am confused when it says I need to update it.

Comment: Make sure you installed Node.js globally, which means if you type `node -v` in root directory,  you get same result.

Comment: Yes, I have it installed globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation available here [bigcommerce/stencil-cli](https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli). Stencil-cli only supports node version 10.x or 12.x. so if you have any other node version switch to either 10 or 12.